# magento-paypal payflow-pro- credit/debit card error

Tags: paypal, payment, checkout, credit-card

I have configured Paypal Payflow Pro and it's working with real paypal credit card details but while using with test mode with American express it throws below error:

```
declined 10759 : Please use another payment card
```

what is exact issue , i am not able to trace it !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cards provided at that URL might have been used so much in TEST mode that they simply don't work anymore.

Instead, generate fresh numbers using the link http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ when you need them. Any number generated there will work with any security code and valid expiration date.

You may be best served contacting PayPal support to trouble shoot because we could be declining for any number of reasons (possibly related to the card itself).